# page.xml addCss not reflecting in site

Tags: magento

I'm using Magento 1.9, and trying to make a Magento theme.

Here is my `app/design/frontend/{MY_PACKAGE}/default/template/layout/`**page.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="1.0">
    <default>
        <label>All Pages</label>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/base.css</stylesheet></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
        <block type="page/html_footer" name="footer" as="footer" template="page/html/footer.phtml">

        </block>
    </default>
</layout>
```

And this is `app/design/frontend/{MY_PACKAGE}/default/template/page/`**1column.phtml**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('head'); ?>
</head>
<body>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('header'); ?>
<div class="middle">
    <div class="col-main"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('content'); ?></div>
</div>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footer'); ?>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('before_body_end'); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

I can't get the `base.css` attached to the page; it does not appear in the source code. What did I miss?

p.s. I *disabled* the cache in Cache Management already; No Design Change applied as well.

---

**UPDATE** The page's `<head>` is rendered as:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Home page</title>
<meta name="description" content="Default Description" />
<meta name="keywords" content="Magento, Varien, E-commerce" />
<meta name="robots" content="NOINDEX,NOFOLLOW" />
<link rel="icon" href="http://www.example.com/dev/skin/frontend/base/default/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://www.example.com/dev/skin/frontend/base/default/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    var BLANK_URL = 'http://www.example.com/dev/js/blank.html';
    var BLANK_IMG = 'http://www.example.com/dev/js/spacer.gif';
//]]>
</script>
<![endif]-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.example.com/dev/skin/frontend/base/default/css/styles.css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.example.com/dev/skin/frontend/base/default/css/widgets.css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.example.com/dev/skin/frontend/base/default/css/print.css" media="print" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.example.com/dev/js/prototype/prototype.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.example.com/dev/js/lib/ccard.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.example.com/dev/js/prototype/validation.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.example.com/dev/js/scriptaculous/builder.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.example.com/dev/js/scriptaculous/effects.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.example.com/dev/js/scriptaculous/dragdrop.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.example.com/dev/js/scriptaculous/controls.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.example.com/dev/js/scriptaculous/slider.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.example.com/dev/js/varien/js.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.example.com/dev/js/varien/form.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.example.com/dev/js/varien/menu.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.example.com/dev/js/mage/translate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.example.com/dev/js/mage/cookies.js"></script>
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.example.com/dev/skin/frontend/base/default/css/styles-ie.css" media="all" />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.example.com/dev/js/lib/ds-sleight.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.example.com/dev/skin/frontend/base/default/js/ie6.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
Mage.Cookies.path     = '/dev';
Mage.Cookies.domain   = '.www.example.com';
//]]>
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
optionalZipCountries = ["HK","IE","MO","PA"];
//]]>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
        var Translator = new Translate([]);
        //]]></script></head>
```

Comment: Where is your base.css located on your Magento ?
hat is your html rendering ? (a copy of the <head> rendered would help us guide you to a solution)

Comment: I put the CSS at `{MAGENTO_ROOT}/skin/frontend/{MY_PACKAGE}/default/css/`

Comment: I just discovered that I accidentally put the page.xml in `app/design/frontend/{MY_PACKAGE}/default/template/layout/`. In several tutorials online, it said it should be put in `app/design/frontend/{MY_PACKAGE}/default/layout/`. However, when I moved to the new path, the whole page is blank. Empty source code. Why? Is it a version difference caused the changes?

Comment: However, the reason I put in `template/` folder is that I followed the tutorial from Magento official website: http://www.magentocommerce.com/design_guide/articles/how-magento-builds-content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see where they do put the layout in the template folder there but mainly, those information are outdated on your 1.9 version. I can recommend you to read the version you can find [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ee114-ce19-rwd-dev-guide).

But for your specific problem, layout have to be in

```
app/design/frontend/{MY_PACKAGE}/default/template/layout/
```

But you also have to understand the fallback mechanism of Magento (further reading [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magentos-theme-hierarchy)) which basically declare a hierarchy of designs.
This way, if Magento does not find a file in the selected design, it is going to look a it in the next hierarchical design.

As from 1.9 the hierarchy changed.

So before 1.9 the hierarchy was static and was like that

1. /skin/frontend/{MY_PACKAGE}/{MY_THEME}/
2. /skin/frontend/{MY_PACKAGE}/default/
3. /skin/frontend/base/default/

As from 1.9 the fallback is dynamic and can be configured in each theme.
For example, if we take the theme shipped with Magento in `app/design/frontend/default/iphone` you would find this file : `etc/theme.xml` which stands

```
<theme>
    <parent>default/default</parent>
</theme>
```

So if Magento does not find a file in the *iphone* theme, it is going to look at it in the *default* theme both under the *default* package. Since the file `etc/theme.xml` in the package *default* and theme *default* stands it as no parent (`<parent/>`) the fallback will end there but could have go further if this theme add defined a parent.

That is also why I asked for the rendered `<head>` of your site because, if the base.css was misplaced, you would have found a call to a base.css but in the wrong location (e.g. a call for http://www.example.com/skin/frontend/base/default/css/base.css)

So, now you know that, you have to know that the layout xml page.xml is responsible for the whole structure of all of your page.
So if you leave your xml like that, you are overriding the page.xml of your Magento.

To do what you want I recommend you to use a file **local.xml** under `app/design/frontend/{MY_PACKAGE}/default/template/layout/` with the exact same code you put in your page.xml and remove that page.xml. That way it should work.

Answer (score 0):

you must add the type , also check if your css its in the correct path

example  of page.xml

```
<default translate="label" module="page">
    <label>All Pages</label>
    <block type="page/html" name="root" output="toHtml" template="page/3columns.phtml">

        <block type="page/html_head" name="head" as="head">
            <action method="addJs"><script>prototype/prototype.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>lib/ccard.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>prototype/validation.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/builder.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/effects.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/dragdrop.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/controls.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/slider.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>varien/js.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>varien/form.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>mage/translate.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>mage/cookies.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>prototype/window.js</script></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>js_css</type><name>prototype/windows/themes/default.css</name></action>


            <block type="page/js_cookie" name="js_cookies" template="page/js/cookie.phtml"/>

            <!-- Remove items which the RWD package is not dependent upon -->
            <action method="removeItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/ie6.js</name></action>

            <!-- Add vendor dependencies -->
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/lib/jquery-1.10.2.min.js</name></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/lib/modernizr.custom.min.js</name></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/lib/selectivizr.js</name></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/lib/matchMedia.js</name></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/lib/matchMedia.addListener.js</name></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/lib/enquire.js</name></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/app.js</name></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/lib/jquery.cycle2.min.js</name></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/lib/jquery.cycle2.swipe.min.js</name></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/slideshow.js</name></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/lib/imagesloaded.js</name></action>
            <action method="addLinkRel"><rel>stylesheet</rel><href>//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,400,500,700,600</href></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/minicart.js</name></action>
```

Comment: that's very different than my `page.xml`. Can you explain further? Where is the `<reference>` tag?

Comment: its different cuase i made modifications , just start with <action method="addItem"><type>js_css</type><name>your/style.css</name> and verify the path

Comment: what is the difference between `addCss` and `addItem` ? Tried your solution, the CSS still does not appear in the source code

Comment: if you use {MAGENTO_ROOT}/skin/frontend/{MY_PACKAGE}/default/css/base css <name> or <stylesheet> (try both) should be /skin/frontend/{MY_PACKAGE}/default/css/base css

Answer (score 0):

Simple add below code in your 1column.phtml.

```
app/design/frontend/{MY_PACKAGE}/default/template/page/1column.phtml:

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<php echo $this->getSkinUrl('css/base.css');?>" media="all" />
```

and add upload base.css to:

```
/skin/frontend/MY_PACKAGE /default/css
```

Delete all Cache then refresh

Comment: But that is a really bad idea because all css and js are included in the layout in Magento, if you break the logic and do that somewhere else for a specific css or js your are never going to find where you did what if you come back later. Look at the shipped layout / phtml and try to understand the reason of why this or that is there and do not make scary workaround like that :/